# Transform specific solutions to general solutions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have this code:

```
Reduce[{a > 0, at > 0, b > 0, bt > 0, c > 0, ct > 0, d > 0, dt > 0, 
  a/at < b/bt, c/ct < d/dt, (a + c)/(at + ct) > (b + d)/(bt + dt), 
  a <= at, b <= bt, c <= ct, d <= dt, a < 7, at < 7, b < 7, bt < 7, 
  c < 7, ct < 7, d < 7, dt < 7}, {a, at, b, bt, c, ct, d, 
  dt}, Integers]
```

It gives me a whole series of solutions. But what I would rather like is a set of simplified conditions with which I can construct possible specific solutions myself. In other words, I am looking for a general solution. Can this be done and if so, how?

Furthermore; I put the values of `a < 7, at < 7, b < 7, bt < 7, c < 7, ct < 7, d < 7, dt < 7` on maximum 7; else my kernel explodes. But rather I would like the limit to be infinite, again I need the general solution, not specific instances. How can this be done?

If infinite is not possible, is it then possible to put it at least at 100 without calculations taking for ages?

Comment: Does `FullSimplify[Reduce[...]]` give you what you need?

Comment: If we find one solution (to the infinite problem), then we can multiply all the variables by any positive integer to get a family of solutions.  If we use `FindInstance` to find a solution in the rationals, we can multiply those values by their LCD to get a family of integer solutions.  But there could be other families of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all solutions up to a limit = i, if you simply test all variations with Table

First Simplify the inequations to accalerate calculations

```
FullSimplify[
   a/at < b/bt && 
   c/ct < d/dt && (a + c)/(at + ct) > (b + d)/(bt + dt), {a > 0, 
   at > 0, b > 0, bt > 0, c > 0, ct > 0, d > 0, dt > 0, a <= at, 
   b <= bt, c <= ct, d <= dt}]

(*     a bt < at b && c dt < ct d && (a + c) (bt + dt) > (at + ct) (b + d)     *)

li[i_] := 
  Flatten[Table[
    If[a bt < at b && 
       c dt < ct d && (a + c) (bt + dt) > (at + ct) (b + d), {{a, b, c, 
       d, at, bt, ct, dt}}, {}], {a, 1, i}, {b, 1, i}, {c, 1, i}, {d, 
       1, i}, {at, a, i}, {bt, b, i}, {ct, c, i}, {dt, d, i}], 8]
```

Up to limit = 4 there are no solutions

```
li[4]

(*     {}     *)
```

Up to limit = 5 gives 18 solutions {a, b, c, d, at, bt, ct, dt} very quickly

```
li[5] // Timing

(*         {0.078, {{1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 1}, {1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1},     {1, 1, 4,
    1, 5, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 
1}, {1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 5, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 
  2, 3, 5, 5, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 
  4}, {3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5}, {4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 3}, {4, 1, 1, 
  1, 5, 1, 5, 4}, {4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 
 5}, {4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 5}, {4, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5}, {4, 2, 1, 
  2, 5, 2, 3, 5}}}     *)
```

Up to limit = 7 takes one second and has 756 solutions.

Up to limit = 12 takes 57 seconds and has 97 172 solutions.

To handle more solutions should be difficult.